# Need a Sweep Gradient algorithm that I can implement for .NET Maui

Tags: graphics, maui, gradient

I am developing a drawn custom control for .NET Maui that requires a sweep gradient. Maui offers linear and radial gradients, but not a sweep gradient. I know that SkiaSharp and Android offer sweep gradients, but I'd rather NOT depend upon third party libraries and I need an implementation that is cross-platform. If I had the basic logic for the rendering of a sweep gradient, I could implement it myself, but I've not been able to find such logic anywhere. Can someone offer me a path to a solution?

I've searched the web and found nothing applicable. I looked at the Skia code but found it nearly indecipherable. I was expecting to find an algorithm I could use but to no avail thus far.

Comment: The only possible way for you to do this is going to be with SkiaSharp or maybe Maui.Graphics, but you will definitely not find ready-made code for it!

Comment: MauiGraphics doesn't have it as I stated in my question. And I do not want to depend on Skia. Those were non-starters from the beginning. I'm looking for an algorithm, not code. I can write the code.

Comment: You can refer to [the sweep gradient in the xamarin forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/effects/shaders/circular-gradients#the-sweep-gradient) and the source code may help you get the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution but some demo code you could use in your custom control. Xaml below is just to demonstrate a usage case, this was sweeping the end tail (0.933->1.0, #CB6235->#00CB6235) of an auto speed gauge, while the whole gauge was painted with solid color (0->0.933, #CB6235):

```
 <draw:SkiaShape.StrokeGradient>

                <draw:SkiaGradient Type="Sweep">
                    <draw:SkiaGradient.Colors>
                        <Color>#CB6235</Color>
                        <Color>#CB6235</Color>
                        <Color>#00CB6235</Color>
                    </draw:SkiaGradient.Colors>
                    <draw:SkiaGradient.ColorPositions>
                        <x:Double>0.0</x:Double>
                        <x:Double>0.933</x:Double>
                        <x:Double>1.0</x:Double>
                    </draw:SkiaGradient.ColorPositions>
                </draw:SkiaGradient>

            </draw:SkiaShape.StrokeGradient>
```

Code behind the drawing is creating a shader that you would add to your SKPaint and draw the shape with it. Tiling default is `SKShaderTileMode.Clamp`.

```
public SKShader CreateGradientAsShader(SKRect destination, SkiaGradient gradient)
  {
      if (gradient != null && gradient.Type != GradientType.None)
      {
          var colors = new List<SKColor>();
          foreach (var color in gradient.Colors.ToList())
          {
              var usingColor = color;
              if (gradient.Light < 1.0)
              {
                  usingColor = usingColor.MakeDarker(100 - gradient.Light * 100);
              }
              else if (gradient.Light > 1.0)
              {
                  usingColor = usingColor.MakeLighter(gradient.Light * 100 - 100);
              }

              var newAlpha = usingColor.Alpha * gradient.Opacity;
              usingColor = usingColor.WithAlpha(newAlpha);
              colors.Add(usingColor.ToSKColor());
          }

          float[] colorPositions = null;
          if (gradient.ColorPositions?.Count == colors.Count)
          {
              colorPositions = gradient.ColorPositions.Select(x => (float)x).ToArray();
          }

          switch (gradient.Type)
          {
          case GradientType.Sweep:
              return SKShader.CreateSweepGradient(
               new SKPoint(destination.Left + destination.Width / 2.0f,
                  destination.Top + destination.Height / 2.0f),
              colors.ToArray(),
              colorPositions,
              gradient.TileMode, (float)Value1, (float)(Value1 + Value2));

          case GradientType.Circular:
          return SKShader.CreateRadialGradient(
              new SKPoint(destination.Left + destination.Width / 2.0f,
                  destination.Top + destination.Height / 2.0f),
              Math.Max(destination.Width, destination.Height) / 2.0f,
              colors.ToArray(),
              colorPositions,
              gradient.TileMode);

          case GradientType.Linear:
          default:
          return SKShader.CreateLinearGradient(
              new SKPoint(destination.Left + destination.Width * gradient.StartXRatio,
                  destination.Top + destination.Height * gradient.StartYRatio),
              new SKPoint(destination.Left + destination.Width * gradient.EndXRatio,
                  destination.Top + destination.Height * gradient.EndYRatio),
              colors.ToArray(),
              colorPositions,
              gradient.TileMode);
          break;
          }

      }

      return null;
  }
```